# Request bloqueado por CORS Policy

Tags: php, ajax, api, rest, slimframework

Eu tô fazendo uma API com Slim Framework e quando eu testo a resposta com Postman tudo funciona muito bem, porém quando eu coloquei no servidor e tentei fazer uma chamada ajax pra testar eu recebi o erro abaixo.

> Failed to load https://api.mydomain.net/usuario/autenticar?xAuthClienteID=2&xAuthChaveApi=3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace&login=admin&senha=teste: Redirect from 'https://api.maydomain.net/usuario/autenticar?xAuthClienteID=2&xAuthChaveApi=3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace&login=admin&senha=teste' to 'https://api.mydomain.net/404.html' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Aqui está o método que eu uso para retornar o Json:

```
public function withCustomJson($meta = null, $data = null)
{
    if (isset($data)) {
        $finalResponse['data'] = $data;
    }

    $finalResponse['meta'] = array(
        'status' => (isset($meta['status']) ? $meta['status'] : null),
        'message' => (isset($meta['message']) ? mb_convert_encoding($meta['message'], "UTF-8", "auto") : null)
    );

    $response = $this->withBody(new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+')));
    $response->body->write($json = json_encode($finalResponse));

    // Ensure that the json encoding passed successfully
    if ($json === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(json_last_error_msg(), json_last_error());
    }

//Allowing CORS as Slim docs states
    $responseWithJson = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    if (isset($meta['codStatus'])) {
        return $responseWithJson->withStatus($meta['codStatus']);
    }
    return $responseWithJson;
}
```

E aqui está minha chamada Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      try {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.mydomain.net/usuario/autenticar',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              xAuthClienteID:'2',
              xAuthChaveApi: '3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace',
              login: 'admin',
              senha: 'teste'
            },
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
      }
      catch(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    </script>
```

Parece que o problema é que não estão ativas as requisições CORS no meu server, então dei uma olhada na documentação do Slim em como ativar e apliquei ao meu método de retornar o Json porém eu continuo recebendo o erro. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Você está local tentando fazer request pra api externa?

Comment: Sim, a api está hospedada no meu servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, eu já tive alguns problemas como estes algumas vezes.
normalmente, tem duas motivações:

1. O servidor não está aceitando requisições CORS (vindas pelo js)
2. A requisição está sendo enviada como OPTIONS e não como GET, POST, etc.

Verifique a primeira opção no serviço.
Existe algo como **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Depois, na sua requisição tente deixar explícito os headers, para que o serviço entenda.

Veja se funciona...

Comment: Eu fiz isso no método de retornar a resposta: $responseWithJson. Foi a primeira coisa que procurei porém não funcionou.

Comment: Qual a linguagem que desenvolveu o serviço? Acho que o problema pode estar nele... Talvez no web.config, ou .htaccess etc

Comment: PHP com Slim Framework

Comment: Veja se isso existe no seu .htacceess: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Comment: O server é nginx.

Comment: Veja esse exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se conseguiu resolver, mas eu uso no Slim Framework.

Tente assim:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;


//cors 
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});
```